# css adjustment with firefox browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, layout, margin

I am working on a wordpress project. The issue is though the container where the content area and sidebar along with the top logo positions seems perfect in chrome with 30px margin-top.
But in firefox the margin seems to go down more, though the margin value is same. Any recommendation for FF compatibility with css would be great...

Answer (score 0):

Hard to see without code, but you may have some problems with the two browsers' base CSS styles being different. You could try using a thing like [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) as a way of normalising these styles before your own stylesheet.

You could also use the web inspector/Firebug in firefox to see what surrounding elements have an effect on the positioning.